# Are there any tools for recording web browser events for seleniumn2?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am looking for something very simple. It can use the Selenium IDE recording tool, but it does not allow me to pick what kind of locators I get.

I want to use:

```
driver.findElement(By.className(str))
```

to locate things. All I need is something which watches which UI elements on a web page get clicked and writes out the class attributes of those tags.

If I use the Selenium IDE recording (and export to the right type of thing), I get:

```
@Test
public void testNav() throws Exception {
  driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
  driver.findElement(By.name("3.1.1.5.1.1")).clear();
  driver.findElement(By.name("3.1.1.5.1.1")).sendKeys("dan");
  driver.findElement(By.name("3.1.1.5.1.5")).click();
  driver.findElement(By.linkText("Products")).click();
  driver.findElement(By.linkText("Categories")).click();
  driver.findElement(By.linkText("Create a Category")).click();
  driver.findElement(By.linkText("Cancel")).click();
  driver.findElement(By.linkText("Products")).click();
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.DisplayAdminProductsLink")).click();
  driver.findElement(By.linkText("Product1")).click();
```

There are problems with this. First, it is not give me any By.className() calls. Why? Those first 3 calls will not help me. The framework I am using puts arbitrary things into the name. How can I get it to see the class attribute?

There actually *are* unique words in the class attribute of all of the above tags. I design my apps so that this is so. Yet it will not use them.

Earlier I asked:

> Why is it doing a "driver.findElement().click()"? This is fragile and does not
>   end up working.
>
> What I need is:
>
> ```
> elt = driver.waitFor(By.className("c")); elt.click();
> ```
>
> *This* will work reproducibly.....

I am considering to be removed from the question, as the findElement() code does work. You need to set a general time-out on the driver. It is not very obvious that this can be done, but it can.

So, continuing on....

I can go to the "Options" and change the order of the "Locator Builders" in eclipse. I can put "css" at the top. Then I get:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name=\"3.1.1.5.1.1\"]")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name=\"3.1.1.5.1.1\"]")).sendKeys("dan");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name=\"3.1.1.5.1.5\"]")).click();
```

The tags are like:

```
<input class="form-control LoginUsernameField" ... />
```

But it does not see the class attribute.... Or I can do this manually.

Comment: Please note that Selenium 1 and Selenium 2 are _versions_. Selenium RC and Selenium WebDriver are _APIs_. Selenium 2 supports _both_ RC and WebDriver calls.

Answer (score 0):

1. Selenium looks for a unique identifier to identify elements in a webpage. `classNames` are a very less desired option for this purpose as they are generally not unique. `Ids` and `names` on the other hand are generally unique. This might be the reason why Selenium IDE is not selecting `classNames` and going for other identifiers.
2. Selenium IDE records user actions. You would have clicked on the element for Selenium IDE to identify it and that is why you are getting `driver.findElement().click()`.
3. If you want to wait for element to wait you can try `implicit wait`.
4. When you want to use `driver.findElement(By.className(str))`, are you sure that there is one and only one element in the webpage that is associated with a `className`? If that is the case you can modify the webdriver code manually to use `className`.

Comment: 1. I am using WebObjects and it needs to, in some components, generate names and ids itself, for its own purposes. The nice thing about the class attribute is that you _can_ add arbitrary strings to it. Say that bootstrap requires 'class="pull-left"' to be in a tag. I can use 'class="pull-left MyClassNameForWhateverIWant" and it does not conflict. I can dynamically generate class attribute to identify specific objects if I want to.

Comment: 3. Would it not be nice if Selenium find methods did an implicit wait themselves? Why would this not be the desired default behavior?

Comment: 4. I can. And then I have to _find_ the class strings I want to use. And then I have no benefit from having done the recording.

Comment: Selenium ideally does an implicit wait but the wait time is zero :p. We have to specify the time to wait in the beginning of the test.